# How to select All the Tables in Access DataBase 2007 using query

Tags: c#-4.0, ms-access-2007

I am working in C#.net.I want to select all table names in the Access Database using Query. Can any one tell... How to select all the tables name from access database using query?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below it will help you...

```
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\myAccess2007file.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
conn.Open();
DataTable tables = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables,new object[]{null,null,null,"TABLE"});
conn.Close();
```

Now the Datatable "tables" have all the access table Info..